# Unable to end conversation using expectedUserResponse field

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to end a conversation dynamically in my dialogflow action.

I've tried setting the expectedUserResponse field to false but so far the only way I've been able to get my action to leave the conversation is to have the toggle button enabled for the intent in the dialogflow setup.

I'm not using any SDK, only passing JSON back and forth in my fulfillment service.

Here's an example of the json that's unsuccessful in ending the conversation:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectedUserResponse": false,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Okay."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having the intent statically declared as an end to the conversation or using the sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is `expectUserResponse`, without the "ed".

So this should work:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": false,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Okay."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  I'm using the google-api-services-dialogflow library to serialize/deserialize the messages.  I assumed the google object was part of the package so anything in it should have been correct, but I forgot I had to create that one manually.since it wasn't included